# Flex Images on same Row but 100% each

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

I have a container with 3 divs that have images inside with overflow: hidden; this container has 100% of width and height of 350px. Inside 3 divs, with background images. Each div with 100% width and same height as the container. All aligned to the right side of the first div because I want to animate it and make a slider. Simple bg image + text slider for each div.

My actual Code:

HTML

```
<div id="container">
   <div id="banner1">
      <h3 class="bannerText">Text1</h3>
   </div>

   <div id="banner2">
      <h3 class="bannerText">Text1</h3>
   </div>

   <div id="banner3">
      <h3 class="bannerText">Text1</h3>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#container {
width: 100%;
height: 350px;
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
display: inline-block;
}

#banner1 {
width: 100%;
height: 350px;
background-image: url("../images/banner1.jpg");
background-color: red;
background-size: cover;
background-position: center center;
position: relative;
float: left;
animation: slide 10s ease-in-out infinite;
}

#banner2 {
width: 100%;
height: 350px;
background-image: url("../images/banner2.jpg");
background-color: fuchsia;
background-size: cover;
background-position: center center;
position: relative;
float: left;
}

#banner3 {
width: 100%;
height: 350px;
background-image: url("../images/banner3.jpg");
background-color: green;
background-size: cover;
background-position: center center;
position: relative;
float: left;
}

bannerText {
color: #fff;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
-webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
-moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
}

@keyframes slide{
10%{
transform:translateX(0);
}
15%, 30%{
transform:translateX(-100%);
}
35%, 50%{
transform:translateX(-200%);
}
55%, 70%{
transform:translateX(-300%);
}
75%, 90%{
transform:translateX(0);
}

}
```

Can someone help me to solve this? also I need it to work on iphones :)

Comment: what is your slideshow? probably like this https://codepen.io/dudleystorey/pen/ehKpi

Comment: thanks @saiful that might work:D!!

Answer (score 0):

what is your slideshow? probably like this

https://codepen.io/dudleystorey/pen/ehKpi

```
<base href="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/">
<div id="slider">
<figure>
<img src="austin-fireworks.jpg" alt>
<img src="taj-mahal_copy.jpg" alt>
<img src="ibiza.jpg" alt>
<img src="ankor-wat.jpg" alt>
<img src="austin-fireworks.jpg" alt>
</figure>
```